# How to limit div to 2 lines of text, expand horizontally if needed to acomodate content

Tags: html, css

I'm a bit new to CSS...

I have a `div` element containing several other `div`s in a row. 
(These are meant to be tabs in a page with several tabs)

I want the height of the `div`s to allow only 2 lines of text, even if the screen size is narrow. If more space is needed to accommodate the text, make the box wider (expand horizontally), up to a certain width (beyond which the text would be truncated).

If the tabs dont fit in the screen, add a scroller, but never make the parent div take a lot of vertical space - never expand vertically.

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ba5okmu6/4/), when i make the browser window narrow it expands vertically, and I want to expand horizontally always.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried adding a min-width?

Comment: @Kjvhout I tried it now but it it still expands vertically, adding more lines of text when I make the browser window narrow.

Comment: Can you maybe give me an example of what you are trying to accomplish? So that I can get a better understanding. Maybe add an image?

Answer (score 1):

Well its totally from scratch so you can pick the idea.

**HTML code**

```
<div id="content">
        <h3>
            Here is content
            <span id="button">+</span>
            <div style="clear:both;">
        </h3>
        Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content Here is content 
    </div>
```

**CSS Code**

```
    <style>
        #content{height: 80px; overflow: hidden;line-height: 22px; width: 500px; border:1px solid #ccc; border-radius:4px;}
        #button{cursor: pointer; float: right; margin-right: 20px;}
    </style>
```

**Script Code**

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('span#button').click(function(){
            var text = $(this).html();
            if(text == '+'){
                $('#content').css('height', '500px');
                $(this).html('-');
            }else{
                $('#content').css('height', '80px');
                $(this).html('+');
            }
        })
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.box {
  border: 1px black solid;
  padding: 20px;
}


.text{
        overflow: hidden;
        display: -webkit-box;
        -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
        -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="box"><span class="text">short text 1</span></div>
      <div class="box"><span class="text">short text 2</span></div>
      <div class="box"><span class="text">This is a long text for example bla bla bla</span></div>
      <div class="box"><span class="text">short text 4</span></div>
      <div class="box"><span class="text">short text 5</span></div>                    
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @zeev barlev, this looks very close to what I want. Indeed just 2 lines of text are displayed, but still the text is truncated with an ellipsis (...), instead of making the `div` take up more width...